# Can I to run several projects in one solution for debugging in VS 2010 Ultimate?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a solution consisting of several executable projects (formally speaking server and its clients). But start-up project is only one (server) but I need to debug and clients too. Now I start their (clients) from folder from shell explorer. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you have to set up your solution to start multiple solutions.

Right-Click on your solution and choose "Set StartUp Projects...".

Then in the Dialog check "Multiple startup projects" and choose the action of those you want to start to "Start" (with debuging) or "Start without debuging".

[image]

Click Ok - done.

Now just hit F5 and all your selected projects should fire up and run.

Comment: no problem - need this all the time when writing WCF-apps. Only problem is that the service may not start in time for the client to notice. I either add a user-input or short wait into the clients that are only compieled in debug for this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about running all the projects at the same time, but there are two things that spring to mind:

1. Open Visual Studio twice. Run the server from one, and the client from the other, or
2. Continue to run the client from the shell, but attach the debugger to the client. Just go to the Debug menu, and select 'Attach to Process'.